# Criando um objeto com um dado interno randômico (random)

Tags: c#, random, números-aleatórios

Estou tentando criar um objeto chamado "Estado", no entanto gostaria que o DDD de cada objeto, ao criar, fosse gerado aleatoriamente.

```
class Estado
{
    public int Resultado { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Estado(string nome)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        rnd();
    }
    public void rnd()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Resultado = random.Next(0, 101);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Estado: "+Nome+"\nDDD: "+Resultado;
    }
}
```

Mas ao rodar:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Estado pe = new Estado("Pernambuco");
        Estado pa = new Estado("Pará");
        Estado pi = new Estado("Piauí");
        Estado pr = new Estado("Paraná");

        Console.WriteLine(pe.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(pa.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(pi.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(pr.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

O resultado saí repetido:

> Estado: Pernambuco
>
> DDD: 60
>
> Estado: Pará
>
> DDD: 60
>
> Estado: Piauí
>
> DDD: 60
>
> Estado: Paraná
>
> DDD: 60

Como posso fazer para cada objeto, ao criar o construtor, ter seu próprio DDD gerado aleatoriamente?

Comment: Dica: http://www.macoratti.net/12/05/c_rand1.htm

Comment: A razao disso é que ele cria apenas um objeto por execucao. A menos que voce repita seco por linha.pra facilitar o entendimento, seu resultado(ramdom) ta sendo executado só uma vez. Se fosse dentro de um for() ou ou chamando o objeto a cada estado seria executado ilimitadas vezes. Por isso voce tem apenas um numero gerado. O tempo como disse o colega nao influencia em nada. Para fazer o teste, no lugar da de toString coloque Random()  fica mais ou menos assimConsole.WriteLine(pa.Random())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É porquê você está instanciando vários `Random` num período de tempo super curto (menor que um milissegundo), e não dá tempo para o `Random` alternar sua semente, e consequentemente, gerar um número aleatório diferente dos anteriormente instanciados.

O que você pode fazer, é travar uma única instância do `Random` e não instanciar vários, e sim somente um, que será global para todos os outros usos. Além disso, travar o seu Thread para que não possa ser executado simultaneamente (e evitar a geração do mesmo número consecutivamente)

```
// dentro da Program, ou qualquer classe estática/não estática
public static Random random = new Random();

class Estado
{
    public int Resultado { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public Estado(string nome)
    {
        Nome = nome;
        rnd();
    }
    public void rnd()
    {
        lock (Program.random) { // evita que o 'random' seja utilizado em threads simultâneos
            Resultado = Program.random.Next(0, 101);
        }
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Estado: "+Nome+"\nDDD: "+Resultado;
    }
}
```

O `Next()` sempre irá um número pseudo-aleatório em relação ao que foi gerado anteriormente, isso se a semente for a mesma.

Documentação do [Random](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8).

Documentação do [Lock](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement).

Comment: Não sabia esse método....

Comment: Qual método @MauryDeveloper ?

Comment: `lock` obrigado!